# Could these spindles attached to the island be load bearing (structural) or can I remove them without hesitation?

Tags: structural, load-bearing

I've attached some photos of the 4 spindles attached from the island to the piece that comes off the ceiling. I'm worried that these 4 spindles could be holding up the center of the house. Is this possible? It doesn't seem like there's a lot there to hold it up.

I tried to include multiple angles for easier viewing.

[image: kitchen view out to living room]

[image: different kitchen view]

[image: view from living room into kitchen]

Comment: That nice solid beam above is what is holding things up. Those spindles (and the island) are not bearing any weight. (They also look nearly identical to some room dividers that we took out years ago - opened up the space tremendously).

Comment: I would be more concern if they were full 4x4 solid posts.  Having about 3/4 of the material removed it is less likely, but still a slim chance.  Can you see inside of the island under where those posts are?

Comment: knock on them. if they don't hurt your knuckle, they are not under compression, which means they bear no weight.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, they are no load bearing.

If they were Steel or concrete there may be a chance, but those spindles are not suitable for carrying any weight other than what may be a small table or something decorative.